# Convex optimization problem with quadratic constraint

Tags: convex-optimization, qclp

$$ \min_{x} c^Tx $$ such that $$||Ax||^2_2 \le 1 $$ where $$A \succ 0$$

I feel like this should be easy but I have been struggling for hours. Is this a second-order cone constraint? How do I begin to find an equivalent problem to solve for x*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\begin{align}
\min_y & \quad d^Ty\\
\text{subject to} & \quad y^Ty \leq 1
\end{align}
$$

has the solution

> $$y^* = -\frac{d}{\lVert d\rVert_2}$$

Can you transform your problem to this form?

Comment: I think so.. y=Ax, d=c^TA ... is this step correct?: x = A^{-1}y so x* = - A^{-1}c^TA / ||c^TA||

Comment: Almost! If we use change of variables $x=A^{-1}y$ then $d^T = c^TA^{-1}$.

For completeness you might need to prove that $A^{-1}$ exists as well as how the solution to the hint is derived.